# Nuxt 3 app deployment always fails because of "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Whenever I try to run the `npm run build` command, the build process won't finish because of the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded". Screenshot of the error is provided below:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Not enough informations to be able to answer, could you provide more insights, some code? Any heavy tasks happening at build? Which node version?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for replying. I don't know but this error is gone after restarting the computer. I'm using `Node v18.15.0` and `Nuxt v3.3.1`. Thank you!